# Angular UI Router - nested routes does not work on templates with nested state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Here is my code:

```
.state('profile',{ 
        url : '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'views/user.html', 
        controller: 'UserCtrl'
      })
      .state('profile.forgot',{ 
        url : '/delivers',
        templateUrl: 'views/user_forgot.html', <- this template not appear, when state is active
        controller: 'forgotCtrl'
      })

<a ui-sref="profile.forgot">Forgot your pasword?</a>
<div class="panel" ui-view=""></div>
```

When i click on link, in ui-view appeared template and controller of parent state.
AngularJS version is 1.2.0-rc.2

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, using 1.2.0-rc.3. Have you found a solution for this, if at all?

Comment: Phil Thomas' answer below is correct. Please accept it.

Comment: @Nick Have u fixed this ?, i am having same problem

Comment: Based on Phil's information, nested states/routes are not working as you expect, simply avoid it, use sth like `.state('profile-forgot')...` instead.

Answer (score 7):

A nested state will render within the `ui-view` element of its parent template (which, if parentless, renders within the root `ui-view`). Make sure you read the '[Nested States & Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#nested-states--views)' section of the docs.

Answer (score -2):

Please Pay attention to parent-child naming convention!

```
.state('profile.forgot',{ 
        url : '/forgot',
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.forgot.html',
        controller: 'forgotCtrl'
      })
```

Comment: a convention has nothing to do with the problem.  he could name it whatever he wants and it would load as long as it's a valid uri

Comment: that could have something to do with language in your controller.  Theoritically, changing `views/profile.forgot.html` to `views/I.love.chocolate.html` shouldn't make a difference, as long as the app knows how to consume the endpoint.